# Can we place a devexpress ComboBoxEdit control in Bar?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I am looking for some approach that can allow me to put a devexpress ComboBoxEdit control in the Bar.

For example:

```
<dxb:BarManager x:Name="barManager" CreateStandardLayout="False" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
<dxb:BarManager.Items>
    <dxb:BarStaticItem Name="lblState" Content="State"/>
    <dxb:BarLinkContainerItem Name="cmbStates" >
    <dxb:BarLinkContainerItem.Content>
           <dxb:ComboBoxEdit DisplayMember="Description" ValueMember="Id" EditValue="{Binding Filter.EquipmentId, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrderStates, Mode=TwoWay}">
           </dxb:ComboBoxEdit>
    </dxb:BarLinkContainerItem.Content>
    </dxb:BarLinkContainerItem>
</dxb:BarManager.Items>
<dxb:BarManager.Bars>
    <dxb:Bar x:Name="Bar" Caption="Bar" UseWholeRow="True">
    <dxb:Bar.DockInfo>
        <dxb:BarDockInfo ContainerName="Top"/>
    </dxb:Bar.DockInfo>
    <dxb:Bar.ItemLinks>
        <dxb:BarStaticItemLink BarItemName="lblState" />
        <dxb:BarLinkContainerItemLink BarItemName="cmbStates" />
    </dxb:Bar.ItemLinks>
    </dxb:Bar>
</dxb:BarManager.Bars>
</dxb:BarManager>
```

Doing so results in the following error:

> UIElement can't be set as content for a BarItemLink.

Is it possible to achieve this? What are the options to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the following markup:

```
<dxb:BarEditItem x:Name="barEditItemComboBox" EditValue="{...}">
    <dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings 
            ItemsSource="{...}"
            DisplayMember="{...}"
            ValueMember="{...}"
        />
    </dxb:BarEditItem.EditSettings>
</dxb:BarEditItem>
```

Also I suggest you review the following articles:

- [Items and Links](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6553)
- [The List of Bar Items and Links](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6646)
- [ComboBoxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6553)